# Weird echo result...where did it come from?

Tags: php

I have this really simply code :

```
<?php
$inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();

echo session_start();
echo print_r($_SESSION);
echo '<br>';
echo print_r($_POST);
echo '<br>';
echo print_r($_GET);
echo '<br>';
include('checkUser.php');

if ($inipath) {

    $_SESSION['haha'] = '1';
    echo 'Loaded php.ini: ' . $inipath .'<br>'. 'hello';
    echo '<br>'. 'new line';
    echo '<br>'. $_SESSION['haha'] . 'hmmm';
} else {
    echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
}

hehe();

?>
```

Which results in :

```
1Array ( [error] => 0 [time] => America/New_York [type] => 99 [apples] => 6 [haha] => 1 ) 1
Array ( ) 1
Array ( ) 1
Loaded php.ini: /var/www/vhosts/system/website.ca/etc/php.ini
hello
new line
1hmmmyeah, you are at checkuser
```

What are these '1' all over the place? The only spot I have a '1' is the $_SESSION['haha']; but removing it does nothing either.

Help!

**Edit:** 
***Why did I get downvoted here?*** I am now barred from asking any more questions. What you think is an inappropriate question, has me scratching my head for hours.

As an actionscript programmer who suddenly takes over a full fledged task of working on web development someone else left behind - full of patches of code mixed together from php, jquery, javascript, ajax, css, sass - i do not really have the chance to work my skill up like normal developers. Sometimes I dont even know what language i am looking at. I dont even know what i dont know. Yesterday I got stuck looking at this <% "content here" %>. I thought this was probably a php shortcut. A friend suggested it was asp. I googled and find nothing. Later on i found out it was underscore.js , only took an hour of snooping around. Thats my current daily life. Most other people are lucky in that they learnt only one language at a time. There seems to be some nice people here, but also others with priviledges they probably shouldnt have. A week later, i am a much better web developer, and happily paying experts-exchange than having to deal with the childish behaviour of smart people with downvoting power.

**Edit 2**: Thank you, to whomever voted me back up so that I am allowed to ask questions again. Cheers.

Comment: You echo the result of session_start(), you echo the result of print_r(), etc... those functions return a Boolean true, which you're echoing, so they appear as a `1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo session_start();
```

[session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) returns true or false. `echo true` == `echo 1`

Answer (score 1):

this is because you're printing the results of functions:

```
echo session_start();
```

will print `1` because it return `true` and `true == 1`.

The same with:

```
echo print_r([...])
```

`print_r()` returns `true` and prints the result by itself.